# Find the pair of bitstrings with the largest number of common set bits

Tags: algorithm, byte, bit

I want to find an algorithm to find the pair of bitstrings in an array that have the largest number of common set bits (among all pairs in the array). I know it is possible to do this by comparing all pairs of bitstrings in the array, but this is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). Is there a more efficient algorithm? Ideally, I would like the algorithm to work incrementally by processing one incoming bitstring in each iteration.

For example, suppose we have this array of bitstrings (of length 8):

```
B1:01010001 
B2:01101010
B3:01101010
B4:11001010
B5:00110001
```

The best pair here is `B2` and `B3`, which have four common set bits.

I found a paper that appears to describe such an algorithm (S. Taylor & T. Drummond (2011); "[Binary Histogrammed Intensity Patches for Efficient and Robust Matching](http://zenithlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/papers/tracking/2011-IJCV-Binary_Histogrammed_Intensity_Patches_for_Efficient_and_Robust_Matching.pdf)"; *Int. J. Comput. Vis.* 94:241–265), but I don't understand this description from page 252:

> This can be incrementally updated in each iteration as the only [bitstring] overlaps that need recomputing are those for the new parent feature and any other [bitstrings] in the root whose “most overlapping feature” was one of the two selected for combination. This avoids the need for the O(N<sup>2</sup>) overlap comparison in every iteration and allows a forest for a typically-sized database of 700 features to be built in under a second.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper you mention?

Comment: Sure.On page 12/25 http://zenithlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/papers/tracking/2011-IJCV-Binary_Histogrammed_Intensity_Patches_for_Efficient_and_Robust_Matching.pdf

Comment: I think it's most likely that you've misunderstood the paper. They only say that they can avoid a O(n²) computation *in each iteration* (and by "O" they seem to mean "Ω") — so I think their algorithm is Ω(n²) overall.

Comment: Yeah.It seems it doesn't need nxn operation in each iteration.but I still can't understand the algorithm. I can do it simply by nxn comparisons but what the paper means by saying "overlaps","parent" and "combination". About O(n²) I don't agree with your comment, Gereth. In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms by how they respond (e.g., in their processing time or working space requirements) to changes in input size. Thanks

Comment: (1) I've written an answer trying to explain what the paper means. See below. (2) The point I was making in my parenthesized comment was that the authors of the paper are sloppily using big-O notation in a couple of places to refer to *lower* bounds on the asymptotic performance of algorithms (big-O notation is for *upper* bounds). To be precise, they ought to write "Ω" in these places instead of "O". But this a very common kind of sloppiness and it's clear in practice what they mean, so it's not worth making a big fuss about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Taylor & Drummond (2011) do not purport to give an O(*n*) algorithm for *finding* the pair of bitstrings in an array with the largest number of common set bits. They sketch an argument that a record of the best such pairs can be *updated* in O(*n*) after a new bitstring has been added to the array (and two old bitstrings removed).

Certainly the explanation of the algorithm on page 252 is not very clear, and I think their sketch argument that the record can be updated in O(*n*) is incomplete at best, so I can see why you are confused.

Anyway, here's my best attempt to explain Algorithm 1 from the paper.

#### Algorithm

The algorithm takes an array of bitstrings and constructs a *lookup tree*. A lookup tree is a binary forest (set of binary trees) whose leaves are the original bitstrings from the array, whose internal nodes are new bitstrings, and where if node A is a parent of node B, then A & B = A (that is, all the set bits in A are also set in B).

For example, if the input is this array of bitstrings:

[image: Array of bitstrings]

then the output is the lookup tree:

[image: Lookup tree]

The algorithm as described in the paper proceeds as follows:

1. Let *R* be the initial set of bitstrings (the *root set*).
2. For each bitstring *f1* in *R* that has no partner in *R*, find and record its *partner* (the bitstring *f2* in *R* − {*f1*} which has the largest number of set bits in common with *f1*) and record the number of bits they have in common.
3. If there is no pair of bitstrings in *R* with any common set bits, stop.
4. Let *f1* and *f2* be the pair of bitstrings in *R* with the largest number of common set bits.
5. Let *p* = *f1* & *f2* be the *parent* of *f1* and *f2*.
6. Remove *f1* and *f2* from *R*; add *p* to *R*.
7. Go to step 2.

#### Analysis

Suppose that the array contains *n* bitstrings of fixed length. Then the algorithm as described is O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) because step 2 is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), and there are O(*n*) iterations, because at each iteration we remove two bitstrings from *R* and add one.

The paper contains an argument that step 2 is Ω(*n*<sup>2</sup>) only on the first time around the loop, and on other iterations it is O(*n*) because we only have to find the partner of *p* "and any other bitstrings in *R* whose partner was one of the two selected for combination." However, this argument is not convincing to me: it is not clear that there are only O(1) other such bitstrings. (Maybe there's a better argument?)

We could bring the algorithm down to O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) by storing the number of common set bits between every pair of bitstrings. This requires O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) extra space.

#### Reference

- S. Taylor & T. Drummond (2011). "Binary Histogrammed Intensity Patches for Efficient and Robust Matching". *Int. J. Comput. Vis.* 94:241–265.

Comment: Then I think I totally had understood the problem.It's now clear.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well for each bit position you could maintain two sets, those with that position on and those with it off.  The sets could be placed in two binary trees for example.

Then you just perform set unions, first with all eight bits, than every combination of 7 and so on, until you find union with two elements.

The complexity here grows exponentially in the bit size, but if it is small and fixed this isn't a problem.

Another way to do it might be to look at the n k-bit strings as n points in a kD space, and your task is to find the two points closest together.  There are a number of geometric algorithms to do this.

Comment: "The complexity here grows **exponentially** in the bit size."

Comment: @GarethRees: Yes, but it is nlogn in the array size.  It wasn't clear which one gets big.